# Yii CGridView sort by id

Tags: php, yii

Hello I need to sort cgridview data table by id DESC how can me do this ?

my wrong code:

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                    'ID'=>array(
                        'desc'=>'ID DESC',
                    ),
            ),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something closer to:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);
$criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
$criteria->order = 'ID DESC';


$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Nameofclass', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria
));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Class Add this line under your search() for showing records in descending order by id.

$criteria->order = 'ID DESC';

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [defaultSort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#defaultOrder-detail) to set it by default

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);
$criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);   

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Nameofclass', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>'ID DESC',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('date', $this->date, true);
    $criteria->compare('last', $this->last, true);
    $criteria->compare('first', $this->first, true);
    //$criteria->order = 'id DESC'; // thats not works, if you use CSORT

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 20
        ),
        'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                     'id' => array("asc" => 'id', "desc" => 'id desc'),
                     'last' => array("asc" => 'last', "desc" => 'last desc'),
                     'first' => array("asc" => 'first', "desc" => 'first desc'),
                     'date' => array("asc" => 'date', "desc" => 'date desc'),
                ),//attributes array
               'defaultOrder' => 'id DESC',//thats the clue, defaultOrder is on the sort array
        ),//sort array
      ));
```